# How to check (programmatically) if a video/audio file has DRM protection?

Tags: ffmpeg, drm

How to check (programmatically) if a video/audio file has DRM protection? Can FFmpeg do this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/108231/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-is-drm-protected

Comment: Depends on the type of video and DRM. There are many different types of DRM, and every one has a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, this heavily depends on the file format. However, since the most common format is likely to be ISOBMFF, that will likely be the case where you most often need to detect it.

For ISOBMFF, it's quite easy, you can simply loop through the "atoms" in the file, and look for a *pssh* atom.

Tools like [mp4dump](https://www.bento4.com/documentation/mp4dump/) will be able to dump the whole structure for you. Alternatively i built a [small tool](https://github.com/colde/psshutil) that will find the pssh box, and tell you which DRM systems it signals.